# Two choices for separate added folders

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to extract content via Inno Setup, however I would like the user to pick between two options, each a different "folder" to extract somewhere. How do I go about doing this? I'm not even sure where to start on InnoSetup help.

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\jorda_000\x64"; DestDir: "{appdata}\Roaming\.mhks"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "C:\Users\jorda_000\x32"; DestDir: "{appdata}\Roaming\.mhks"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files
```

This is what I have in the script for files after adding them. Basically, they pick either 64-Bit or 32-Bit and it updates files in the program folder folder.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I didn't fully understand the "Components" section of Inno Setup.

Added.

```
[Components]
Name: "main"; Description: "64-bit"; Types: full compact custom;
Name: "alt"; Description: "32-bit"; Types: full compact custom;
```

Comment: Don't forget to use a `Check:...` parameter to hide the 64-bit options on a 32-bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

This will create 2 option in Components page.If User choose one then other one can not be installed.

**Here is the sample script:**

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\jorda_000\x64"; DestDir: "{appdata}\Roaming\.mhks"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Components: sixfour
Source: "C:\Users\jorda_000\x32"; DestDir: "{appdata}\Roaming\.mhks"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Components: threetwo
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Components]
Name: "threetwo"; Description: "Main(32 bit)"; Types: custom; Flags: exclusive
Name: "sixfour"; Description: "Main(64 bit)"; Types: custom; Flags: exclusive

[Types]
Name: "custom"; Description: "Custom"; Flags: iscustom
```